# Circular pattern - preposition before angle for two members only

Tags: prepositions

I'm trying to describe that holes are placed in a circular pattern. When there are for example 6 holes in a circle I write:  6x hole every 60 deg.

But how to describe when there are only two holes? "Every" seems inappropriate to me.

It's for a drawing, so it has to be short as possible.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: You cannot place two of anything "in a circular pattern", it defies logic. If you mean the two holes are equidistant on a circle, then you place them "180º apart", or "diametrically opposite". I'm not sure your question belongs on an English site, it's more a basic question of geometry.

Comment: @Chappo  Of course you can place two of something in a circular pattern. If you have a few hundred round electrical connectors that are all the same except for clocking, you need to be able to describe a few hundred clocking patterns, and they may include patterns with zero, one and two keys.  See page G3 of this Hubbell catalog for [example of connector clockings](https://www.connecticc.com/pdf/hubbell-pin-and-sleeve-devices-and-mechanical-interlocks-catalog.pdf)

Comment: Lluser, you provide the angle to each hole from a [datum reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datum_reference). We also have an [engineering.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PhilSweet I know About engineering Stack, but this is purely language question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase you might want to use is [diametrically opposed](https://grammarist.com/phrase/diametrically-opposed/), which literally means at opposite ends of a diameter, which is a straight line. Unfortunately (?), it also has an idiomatic meaning, but as I don’t think your holes dislike each other.

Alternatively, "every" is ok if it follows your existing convention. In theory, you could have more than two holes spaced every 180 deg, they’d just be co-located, so only two holes need drilled. I’m curious as to why you wouldn’t just draw the holes with a dotted straight line (or marked/labelled angles) between them. Two points can only define a straight line on a flat surface.